# Where do R scripts from packages get put when installed on Mac?

Tags: r

This is a ridiculously simple question, but I've installed a package from GitHub, and can find where it's been installed on my Mac (Ventura), at `/Library/Framework/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/<package-name>`, but the GitHub for the package has R scripts, which are not in that directory.

I want to interrogate my local installation so that I can find where there may be an issue with one of the R functions in the R script when I call it using my data.

EDIT:
Following the comment from @r2evans below, the github I've installed is here: https://github.com/PoisonAlien/maftools, with the R scripts in the `R` directory in the base folder.

Comment: Where are the R scripts within the github repo? Perhaps it would help to link to the package github repo itself.

Answer (score 0):

By default installation goes to the first element of `.libPaths()`:

```r
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"           
>
```

On my system (by my choice and preference) to `/usr/local`.

But better still, you don't need to know or care as the extra-useful function `system.file()` can look it up for you!  Here I know that "whereever" my `littler` package is installed, it has scripts in subdir `examples`. So:

```r
> system.file("examples", "build.r", package="littler")
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/littler/examples/build.r"
>
```

Note that this also takes care of the file path separator, here `/` on Linux.  And this functions returns an empty string for non-existing files or paths.

Comment: There are no R files in the Mac location where this package has been installed (/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library)

Comment: That is normal.  R source files are preparsed on installation. In the `R/` directory, you will likely have a single file named as the package (container loader code), a larger file with extension `.rdb` and a smaller file with extension `.rdx`.

Comment: So how do I edit an R file that has been preparsed to make changes so I can see where the problem lies?

Comment: From the _source_ of the package, either working off the CRAN source (in a `.tar.gz` file) or by working from the souce repository,